# WordPress Pagination buttons show the same posts on all pages

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I am having an issue with the pagination on my WordPress blog page. The next and previous page buttons take me to a new page but all pages show the same 10 blog posts.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php
$args = array('cat' => '-27');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
    endwhile;
    global $wp_query;
    $total = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    if ( $total > 1 )  {
        if ( !$current_page = get_query_var('paged') )
        $current_page = 1;
            if( get_option('permalink_structure') ) {
                $format = '?&paged=%#%';
            } else {
                $format = 'page/%#%/';
            }
            echo paginate_links(array(
                'base'     => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
                'format'   => $format,
                'current'  => $current_page,
                'total'    => $total,
                'mid_size' => 4,
                 'type'     => 'list'
            ));
    }
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!